# needed thumbnail tiles scroller/slideshow/slider

Tags: slider, slideshow, scroller

I'm looking for a thumbnail tiles scroller/slideshow/slider
Here is the example http://safari.to/clients
Really appreciate if anyone could help :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you see something on any website, its easy to inspect and see how they are doing it.

The website mentioned by you is doing it using their own script instead of a plug in

See the following code from http://safari.to/assets/js/script.js. You will also need to see how they are styling the sliders by inspecting their CSS code

```
// Agencies slide
    var clients = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;  // nth-child indices start at 1
    if ( clients == 1){
        $('.agencies.clients').hide();
    }
    else 
    {
        $('.brands.clients').hide();    
    }

    $('.agencies menu a').bind({
        click: function() 
        {
            if(sliding) return false;

            var pointer = $(this);
            var width = $('.agencies .scroller li').length * 137;
            var current = parseInt($('.agencies .scroller').css('left'));
            var distance = 0;

            if(pointer.is('.right-pointer'))
            {
                if(current == -1920) distance = current - 137;
                else distance = current - 960;
                if((width + current) < 960)
                    distance = current;
            }
            else 
            {
                distance = current + 1097;
                if(distance > 0)
                    distance = 0;
            }

            sliding = true;

            $('.scroller').animate({
                left: distance + 'px'
            }, 300,
            function() 
            {
                sliding = false;
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it already, now I'm looking for freeware code / Open Source in same pattern.